# How to delete the monitoring data of a cluster node that is offline?

Tags: tidb, tikv, tidb-pd

I have deployed TiDB in our production environment. I want to know how to delete the monitoring data of a cluster node that is offline.

Answer (score 0):

The offline node usually indicates the TiKV node. You can determine whether the offline process is finished by the pd-ctl or the monitor. After the node is offline, perform the following steps:

1. Manually stop the relevant services on the offline node.
2. Delete the `node_exporter` data of the corresponding node from the Prometheus configuration file.
3. Delete the data of the corresponding node from Ansible `inventory.ini`.